# How to use rsync to overwrite only destination files which have changed from source?

Tags: rsync

We have a source folder which contains the correct base state of a test system.
Currently, we copy that source folder over to the destination folder each time and overwrite everything with the base state.
When the tests run in the destination folder they modify a number of files, but not all of them.

The problem we are facing is that the copy command takes a huge amount of time to copy everything over, including node_modules and vendor files, which are required for the base state.
I want to use rsync to only overwrite those files which have been modified from the base state, in order to save time on the test run.

What would be the rsync syntax for doing that?

I have read lots about using it to sync only newer files, but in our instance the destination folder will always be newer than the source, so that doesn't work.

Comment: What copy utility are you using? Most/many have some kind of option to only copy modified files or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rsync will do this by default, by comparing the hashes, mtimes, sizes and other attributes (depending on the options you've selected). This is the very point of rsync; to only copy data that has changed to make it more efficient than a straight copy.

Edit to add: this is assuming you have an rysnc friendly file system at both ends. If, for example, you are using NTFS then entire files will be copied, but still only those that have changed.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what it's doing now. The build process replaces all of the node_modules and the vendor files, which means to RSync's eyes they have been updated, even though they have been updated with exactly the same thing.
Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @KayleighWhitehurst I think by default it will sync a file if the mtimes differ. You might want to use some combination of --ignore-times and --size-only to make it skip these files if they otherwise match.